# App crashes saying Collection expression type UIView*' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:object:count"'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UIImageView` inside a tableView and want to remove it programmatically when the row is clicked.

```
   -(void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

            for (UIView *subview in  tableView)
            {
                if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
                {
                 [subview removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }
}
```

the app crashes when i click on the table row. `Warning : Collection expression type UIView* may not respond to countByEnumeratingWithState:object:count"`
Same message is lodged for the app crash. What i have missed here? I have only pasted the relevant portion of code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Code should be  like

```
for (UIView *subview in  tableView.subviews)
```

Comment: This actually answered my question as well! But I'm not exactly sure why. Do you have any insight?

Comment: @narner In the question he was trying to remove the subView of a tableView, but he mistakenly written an iteration like `for (UIView *subview in  tableView)` . Here `tableView` is a single view. We are supposed to get its subViews `tableView.subviews`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop to

```
  for (UIView *subview in  [tableView subviews])
  {
       if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
       {
           [subview removeFromSuperview];
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It may help you..

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
         NSArray *cells = [tableView visibleCells]; 
        UITableViewCell *currentCell = nil;
        for (UITableViewCell *cell in cells)
        {
            NSIndexPath *currentIndexPath =  [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
            if(currentIndexPath.row == indexPath.row && currentIndexPath.section == indexPath.section)
            {
                currentCell = cell;
                break;
             }
        }
   for(UIView *subView in [[currentCell contentView] subviews])
    {
        // do your stuff.
    }
```

}